# Sketch Up and Open GL ES

Tags: opengl-es, .obj, sketchup

Hi I have created a model in Sketch Up and want to export if for use in my open GL ES app. My question is. do I need to specify that I want the output to be all triangles and not polygons. As obviously ES doesn't support other shapes. And If so How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OpenGLES only supports triangles, yes you have to split up your polygons to become triangles. The process of splitting up faces to triangles is called "triangulation". A quick google search told me that sketchup doesn't have a native function for this, so you probably have to install a plugin like this one: http://osbo.com/sketchup/triangulate/